# Summary band subreport displays only last value

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, subreport

I am displaying list of string values in detail band of the report , it works fine. And i want to **draw 5 graphs in summary band**. I tried in summary band it took all the values and generated report but **summary band height was limitted**. so i drawed only three graphs in that space. **I moved to sub report to draw all the 5 graphs**.
i passed values to subreport through parameter map. I got all the 5 graphs, but the **graph is drawed using the last value passed to the subreport**. I want to draw the graphs with all the values passed to it. How to to this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the same datasource as you're using in your main report. Should work fine.

You can achieve this using the property $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE} in your subreport data source expression, but don't forget to set the connection type as well.